# Create dynamic SEO friendly url in core PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I wanted to create seo friendly urls in `core php`, for example I have a category called **Home and Furniture** and in this category i am adding a product called **Walton Sofa** , assume that my domain name is **www.mydomain.com**.

If I create above category, my url should be **www.mydomain.com/home-and-furniture** and in this page all the products shouls be listed. If I create above product in same category, my product page url should be  **www.mydomain.com/home-and-furniture/walton-sofa** this is product info page.

How can I create this kind of url in `core php` using `.htaccess`.

Here is what I tried,

To create category i was creating a folder(home-and-furniture) and to create a product i was creating a `.php` page in above named folder. So this is not good idea to create static folder and file.

Comment: Show your original urls and your current htaccess rules.

Comment: Actually I was creating folders for each category and php files for each product. Url is www.mydomain.com/home-and-furniture/walton-sofa.php and here iam not using .htaccess file

Comment: Is this your original url `www.mydomain.com/home-and-furniture/walton-sofa.php` if yes then you want to remove `.php` i guess and home-and-furniture is your folder

Comment: First, i dont want create folders and files and this is not good idea to create static folders and files, if I do like this there will be n number of files.

Comment: Okay, so where are your original files resides in root `/` or there is some specific folder for project.

Comment: I would recommend using a router library (unless you, for some reason, really don't want to use a tried and tested method for this kinds of stuff). It will make it a breeze to add other types of rewrites/patterns and you don't need to update the .htaccess every time you do that (and easier to use with other web servers that doesn't support .htaccess-files, since it's PHP that does the most magic).

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar, all the files are in root only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your `.htaccess`

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ product.php?pr_url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ category.php?cat_url=$1
```

Comment: Write category page code in category.php using $_GET['cat_url'] and product page code in product.php using $_GET['pr_url'].